# Adobe API for accessing Adobe Cloud documents?

Tags: api, rest, pdf, adobe

I've searched for hours on the adobe API websites/documentations and can't seem to find an API to access (list, download etc...) documents stored on the Adobe cloud (for example when you use adobe scan on mobile phone), they are all about processing PDFs. Is there an API that does what I ask for ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to the Adobe Document Cloud.